# gridjs: server, how to map data for a simple json array

Tags: json, gridjs

I'm a java-script newbee, that's why I struggle with the mapping of a simple json array, if it is a response from a server. I've tested it with static json, and it works as expected:

```
    new gridjs.Grid({
        columns: [{
             id: 'dateTime',
             name: 'Timestamp'
          }, {
             id: 'host',
             name: 'Host'
          }, {
             id: 'ipv4',
             name: 'IPv4'
          }, {
             id: 'ipv6',
             name: 'IPv6'
          }],
          data: [
              {"dateTime": "2021-12-02 03:11:30.501","host": "master.myhost.com","ipv4": "93.215.66.14", "ipv6": "2003:cc:2fff:9e4:2e91:abff:febf:d839"}, 
              {"dateTime": "2021-12-02 03:44:29.494", "host": "test.myhost.com", "ipv4": "93.203.250.190", "ipv6": "n/a"}, 
          ]
        }).render(document.getElementById("wrapper"));
```

But if the same json array is delivered by a server, I don't know how to define my data mapping. That's what I've tried:

```
    new gridjs.Grid({
        columns: [{
             id: 'dateTime',
             name: 'Timestamp'
          }, {
             id: 'host',
             name: 'Host'
          }, {
             id: 'ipv4',
             name: 'IPv4'
          }, {
             id: 'ipv6',
             name: 'IPv6'
          }],
          server: {
              url: "http://localhost:8080/info/zone-log",
              then: data => data.map([data.dateTime, data.host, data.ipv4, data.ipv6]) 
          }
        }).render(document.getElementById("wrapper"));
```

I get the following error on the JS console: '[Grid.js] [ERROR]: TypeError: [...] is not a function'.

Can somebody explain me, how to do the data mapping correctly?

**Edit**

Server response:

```
curl -i http://localhost:8080/info/zone-log
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 01 Mar 2022 08:53:39 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

[{"dateTime":"2021-12-02 03:11:30.501","host":"master.myhost.com","ipv4":"93.215.66.14","ipv6":"2003:cc:2fff:9e4:2e91:abff:febf:d839"},{"dateTime":"2021-12-02 03:44:29.494","host":"ursa.myhost.com","ipv4":"93.203.250.190","ipv6":"n/a"}, ...}
```

java-script console log:

```
data 
Array(191) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
[0…99]
​​0: Object { dateTime: "2021-12-02 03:11:30.501", host: "master.myhost.com", ipv4: "93.215.66.14", … }
​​1: Object { dateTime: "2021-12-02 03:44:29.494", host: "ursa.myhost.com", ipv4: "93.203.250.190", … }

[Grid.js] [ERROR]: TypeError: [...] is not a function   log.ts:12:21
```

Comment: Please edit your question and share the response you get from the request to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like data that you are getting is not an array. Hence data.map() is giving type error. Can you please console log the data and see what's coming?

```
new gridjs.Grid({
    columns: [{
         id: 'dateTime',
         name: 'Timestamp'
      }, {
         id: 'host',
         name: 'Host'
      }, {
         id: 'ipv4',
         name: 'IPv4'
      }, {
         id: 'ipv6',
         name: 'IPv6'
      }],
      server: {
          url: "http://localhost:8080/info/zone-log",
          then: data => {
                  console.log("data", data);
                  return data.map([data.dateTime, data.host, data.ipv4, data.ipv6]) 
                }
      }
    }).render(document.getElementById("wrapper"));
```

Most probably the required array is inside another object in data.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I've edit my question and add some logging entries from the js-console. The response from the server seems to be correct. But something seems to be wrong with the mapping I guess ...

Comment: @ThiloSchwarz - Looks like you are not using map properly. it has to be

data.map(res => [res.dataTime, res.host, res.ipv4 ]);

check this out for example: https://gridjs.io/docs/server-side/

using map properly should solve the problem. Do let me know if not. Happy to help!

Comment: Also do give a thumbs up if your issue gets resolved, I would be happy to know!

Comment: Thanks a lot, the mapping works know.

Comment: @AdityaAkella Thank you! This worked perfectly for server calls. I think it should be made the answer.